# 301 redirect multiple domains to single domain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the following in my .htaccess file and works at main level but not subfolders. So the problem is http://mydoamin.com/folder/file.php redirects to the wrong location http://mydomain.com/file.php and the subfolder is lost.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the apache config create another vhost site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias anotherdomain.com anotherdomain.org ...
  RedirectPermanent / http://www.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks but I need each individual webpage to go to the coresponding webpage on the other domain.  The file structure is the same.

Comment: You can add as much domains as you want to ServerAlias

Comment: I need http://olddomain.com/folder/page4.html to go to http://mewdomain/folder/page4.html.  I believe the virtual host will only direct all traffic to http://newdomain.com and not the unique webpages.

Comment: Test it, before you "believe" something! Everything under / will be redirected to the destination with the same structure. That's one important point to not forget the trailing slash after the domain.